# Ruby version error Bundle install error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Ruby 2.4.2. When I run `bundle install`, it shows the following error:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.4.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It showing this error because in your Gemfile you have specified Ruby version '2.3.3'.

You have two options: one is to remove the Ruby version declaration from your Gemfile, the second to specify the version that is installed on the system in Gemfile.

```
ruby '2.4.1'
```

It should be like that in your gemfile.

If you want to use Ruby '2.4.2' then install it in your system and specify the same in Gemfile. You can use [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) to manage multiple versions of Ruby.